# deploying local app on shiny server aws my-app

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, shiny-server, rstudio-server

I have successfully deployed my own instance in AWS running on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS with the 64-bit version. how can I deploy my local app I have created to my instance so that it is running on my shiny server in AWS? running `sudo cp -R ~/MY-APP /var/shiny-server/www/` I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, were you using a resource/guide that suggested you deploy to `/var/shiny-server/`? Just wanted to make sure we don't have a guide out there we need to update.

Comment: http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jay/EC2/CreateFromScratch.html I found this and tried it out first. Your comment below suggests I need to redeploy. Will try that out then.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: recent versions of Shiny Server expect applications to be hosted in `/srv/shiny-server/`.

Long answer: Try out one of the Quick Start Guides in the [Admin Guide](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/#quick-start). The first one will show you how to deploy a simple Shiny App. It will walk you through each command to get up and running with a sample application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ramazon package**, that I developed after facing the same problem. 
This package takes care of all steps needed to deploy a shiny app on an Amazon ec2 instance.

User is required to **just run the ramazon() function**, passing the public_DNS and the key pair name.

You can find the **package repo** at: https://github.com/AndreaCirilloAC/ramazon

Hope this will help you out.

Andrea